# Android : cacerts.bks is not found in the repository

Tags: android

The defined path for cacerts.bks is not found in the Android device at system/etc/security/cacerts.bks - I want to verify whether my device owns it or not , how to check this ?

Regards
SS

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try to list the security directory content..

```
adb shell ls /system/etc/security/
```